# My sql installation error in Ubuntu - 12.04

Tags: mysql, regex, linux, ubuntu-12.04

When i write the command

```
    sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

I get the following error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server-5.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql-server-5.5'
```

Please tell me how to remove it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error means that the package name is not correct, try

```
apt-cache search mysql-server
```

write down the package name you want to install and retry

```
sudo apt-get install correct-package-name
```

Another answer might be that you don't have the correct repository where the package is stored. From [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/database/) you can see that you should enable the `security` repository. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) you can see how to do that.

Edit:

As Tuim stated, it can also be the '.' in the name, but that's only the case when the exact expression is not found (apt-get manual):

> If no package matches the given expression and the expression contains one
>   of ".", "?" or "*" then it is assumed to be a POSIX regular expression, and it is applied to all package names in the database. Any matches are then installed (or removed).

So I still think that you have an issue with the repository.

Comment: When I run apt-cache search mysql-server I am getting a blank screen only.. No suggestions :(

Comment: As I said, you need to add the correct repository to your Ubuntu source. The second link I posted explains how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Due to the '.' in the package name it is treated as a regex.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try running sudo apt-get install mysql-server I  get the following error Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate

Comment: Please see Cynical his answer above.